# How to access API Service for types and mutations from within lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

We are currently working on an application using AWS Amplify. We have 10/15 Lambda functions defined through our Amplify project along with using several other plugins. The project itself is an Angular Application.

Right now, we are working on interfacing some 3rd party services into our Amplify project that utilizes publishing mutations for real time updates using @aws_subscribe. We can trigger these just fine based on the solution using a HTTP request; however, we are wondering if it is possible to reuse the mutation operations already generated within the *API.service.ts* file to provide consistent typing for both "clients". This will help maintain type control across both "clients" and catch errors earlier. It also prevents us from re-writing mutations/queries down the road.

Our current solution is working but seems inefficient.

*Query Statement*

```
const PublishReportingLocationWorkflowProgressUpdateMutation = `mutation PublishReportingLocationWorkflowProgressUpdate(        $id: ID!,        $status: WorkflowProgressUpdateStatus!,        $reportingLocation_id: String!        ) {            publishReportingLocationWorkflowProgressUpdate(result: {id: $id, status: $status, reportingLocation_id: $reportingLocation_id}) {                id                status                reportingLocation_id            }        }`;
```

*HTTP Request Body*

```
{
                query: PublishReportingLocationWorkflowProgressUpdateMutation,
                operationName: 'PublishReportingLocationWorkflowProgressUpdate',
                variables: {
                    id: event.Payload.executionID,
                    status: 'COMPLETE',
                    reportingLocation_id: event.Payload.reportingLocation.id                }
```

*HTTP Call*

```
let response = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: process.env.API_URL,
            data: mutation,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'x-api-key': process.env.API_KEY,
            }
        });
```